# how to filter objects by a specific choice

Tags: django

I have model like this:

```
class ScientificInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_approved = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=(('0', 'yes'), ('1', 'no')), blank=True)
    is_interviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

how can I filter this model by is_approved field which is a choicefield? I wrote this line but doesnt work

```
approved = ScientificInfo.objects.filter(is_approved__in='0').all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `exact` field lookup would probably make more sense here:

```
approved = ScientificInfo.objects.filter(is_approved__exact='0').all()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exact

Comment: it is not working

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I dont get any errors. it returns an empty context

Comment: And you're sure that `ScientificInfo.objects.all()` returns objects with an `is_approved` of `0`?

Comment: yes it works Im sure

Comment: This should work then. If you find the ID X of one of your objects with `is_approved='0'`, can you then post the output of `ScientificInfo.objects.get(id={X}).is_approved`?

Answer (score 0):

Put `values` inside `()` as

```
approved = ScientificInfo.objects.filter(is_approved__in=('0')).all()
```

Comment: it is not working either

Comment: Any error you are getting with this process? Also try with square brackets as `is_approved__in=['0']`